# Solve complex equation $\cos(iz)$=$\cos(z)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm not sure how to find all solutions. Of course, it's true for $z=0$. I also know that $\cos(iz)=\cosh(z)$. So far I've managed to transform it into such an equation: $\cos(y)\cosh(x)=\cos(x)\cosh(y)\land\sin(y)\sinh(x)=-\sin(x)\sinh(y)$, but I don't think that was helpful. I'll really appreciate any help.

Comment: Developing your idea, note that $\cos$, $\cosh$, $\sin$, $\sinh$ all take a real argument and return a real value, so you've translated your problem in complex numbers to real numbers. Write $f(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\cosh(x)}$ and $g(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\sinh(x)}$ and you have $f(y)=f(x)$ and $g(y)=g(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I wrote it down, but I still don't see what it might imply.

Comment: @Blitzer Have you missed a minus sign in the sine/sinh equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z,w\in\Bbb C$, then $\cos(z)=\cos(w)\iff z\pm w\in2\pi\Bbb Z$. So,\begin{align}\cos(z)=\cos(iz)&\iff z\pm iz\in2\pi\Bbb Z\\&\iff(1\pm i)z\in2\pi\Bbb Z\\&\iff z=(1\pm i)k\pi\end{align}for some $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @FShrike No, since $\dfrac2{1\pm i}=1\mp i$.

Comment: Whoops, I did not read too carefully. +1

Answer (score 2):

I would not use hyperbolic functions, but leave the equation in the form $\cos(iz)=\cos(z)$.

Use the trigonometric sum-product relations to render

$\cos(iz)-\cos(z)=2\sin\left(\dfrac{(1-i)z}{2}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{(1+i)z}{2}\right).$

Since the difference on the left is required to be zero, one of the sine factors must be zero on the right, forcing $(1\pm i)z/2$ to equal a multiple of $\pi$. From there it's easy.

Comment: I thought about it but wasn't sure if this was the same equality in complex numbers. In this case, it won't affect the result, but shouldn't it be $-2$?

Comment: Note the order of subtraction in the first sine factor on the right, reversed from the cosine difference on the left.

Answer (score 0):

If you express

$$
\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\\
\cosh x=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}
$$

then you will find that $\cos(iz)=\cosh(z)$. I tried this out numerically with random values of $z$ and find it to be true.